# Весенняя майская Грузия - нужна ли здесь запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

Весенняя майская Грузия - нужна ли здесь запятая?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Можно так выразиться, но только нужно *майская* произнести с интонацией уточнения:

***Весенняя, майская, Грузия. Или: Весенняя - майская - Грузия. Или: Весенняя (майская) Грузия.***

Answer (score 0):

Нет, запятая не нужна, потому что прилагательные характеризуют Грузию с разных сторон, взаимно дополняя друг друга, и не являются однородными.

***Обновление:***

Но, как правильно заметил behemothus, тут действительно что-то вроде плеоназма. Грузия либо весенняя, либо майская. Если майская, то и так понятно, что она весенняя, а если сказать "весенняя", то это будет немного менее точно, поэтому если надо уточнить, то нужно исключить "весеннюю". Одно из двух.

Comment: Да, спасибо большое. Мне тоже так кажется, но не знала, как объяснить.

Comment: Интересно, какие две ***разные*** стороны у "весенней" и "майской"?! Тут плеоназмом попахивает, а вы без запятой предлагаете.

Comment: Ой, действительно, даже и не вдумался, какой выходит смысл! Сейчас подкорректирую ответ.